# Profiling data visualization

Tags: performance, profiling, visualization

Does anyone know how this is rendered:

http://blogs.oracle.com/realneel/resource/open_table_hash_walk.svg

I really like this horizontal visualization of profiling data, where all the calls are instantly visible, rather than tree structure type of visualizations that you can find in most of the profilers.

I was wondering if the above image was rendered using some free or commercial script/component, or if anyone knows of similar visualization component.

Comment: This is called a "flame graph" and another guy interested in them is Brendan Gregg - google his name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The author is Neelakanth Nadgir, a former Sun engineer, and his blog page about the script is [here](http://blogs.oracle.com/realneel/entry/visualizing_callstacks_via_dtrace_and).

Comment: @Leonid As you surely know, Sun underwent some big changes lately. You may find the author writing now at http://realneel.blogspot.com